# how to remove quicktabs extra url

Tags: uri

I have a quicktabs on my homepage. When the tabs are clicked the url of homepage changed to like this:

http://www.example.com/home?qt-homepage_tab_menu=0#qt-homepage_tab_menu
.
.
.
What should I do if I only want to have http://www.example.com when any tab is clicked?

Thank you!

Comment: try this https://www.drupal.org/node/421226#comment-8852413

Answer (score 0):

I believe that could happen if you have a Javascript error on your page, or that you have Javascript disabled in your browser. For the former, open the error console (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>J</kbd> in Firefox and Chrome) and try to figure out what might be causing it.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you enzipher for the tip. There were few javascript/jQuery errors but the main problem was the file google_analytics_et.js. I searched and found a patch from here: https://www.drupal.org/files/google_analytics_et-single_event-1870694-0.patch

Problem solved. Hope this will help other people. I have spent too much of time on this.